# Alternative to do_shortcode( '[shortcode] $content [/shortcode]' )

Tags: php, wordpress

I found [this](https://konstantin.blog/2013/dont-do_shortcode/), that function invokes a fairly large regex every time it is called.

I too found [alternative to do_shortcode( '[shortcode]' )](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25435)

In the article there is the following code:

```
$old = do_shortcode( '[gallery columns="2" ids="19,20,21,22"]' );
$new = do_single_shortcode( 'gallery', array( 'columns' => 2, 'ids' => '19,20,21,22' ) );
```

But how to apply it to which uses opening and closing tags [shortcode] [/ shortcode], there is also flanked content?

How change my this code to alternative:

```
<?php
  $my_linkdownload = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'linkdownload', true);
  if( ! empty( $my_linkdownload ) ) {
echo do_shortcode('[pms-restrict subscription_plans="8"] <a href="' . $my_linkdownload . '" target="_blank"><img src="http://koran.pustakakoran.com/img/etc/pdf.png"> </a>[/pms-restrict]');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the shortcode's callback function directly.

So for instance, the `[gallery]` shortcode callback is `gallery_shortcode()`, and you can do:

```
echo gallery_shortcode( $attr );
```

Comment: Can you apply it to my code above, which uses opening and closing tags [shortcode] [/ shortcode], there is also flanked content. thank for your answer.